# How can I call a return value from ScriptA.cs in ScriptB.cs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a button that has to be pushed and when the button is pushed the light is turned on. **Can I take a return Boolean value from a function in ScriptA.cs and then call the return value in ScriptB.cs ?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following codes?

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool ReturnRandomBool()
    {
        int randomInt = Random.Range(0, 2);
        return randomInt == 0;
    }
    
    void Start()
    {
         ScriptB.Instance.DoSomeThingBasedOnValue(ReturnRandomBool());
    }
}
```

|

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScriptB Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void DoSomeThingBasedOnValue(bool val)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```